# javascript split

Tags: javascript, split

I can use JavaScript's split to put a comma-separated list of items in an array:

```
var mystring = "a,b,c,d,e";
var myarray = mystring.split(",");
```

What I have in mind is a little more complicated. I have this comma separated string:

```
"mystring_109_all,mystring_110_mine,mystring_125_all"
```

how do i split this string in to an array

Comment: Please clarify how the array should look like.

Comment: The same as you already wrote in your first example. What should the result be?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, there's really nothing more complicated. It's still a simple split on a comma.

Answer (score 11):

You can provide a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for *split()*, so to split on a comma or an underscore, use the following:

```
var mystring = "mystring_109_all,mystring_110_mine,mystring_125_all";
var myarray  = mystring.split(/[,_]/);
```

If you're after something more dynamic, you might want to try something like ["Search and don't replace"](http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/), a method of using the *replace()* function to parse a complex string.  For example,

```
mystring.replace(/(?:^|,)([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)(?:,|$)/g,
  function ($0, first, second, third) {
    // In this closure, `first` would be "mystring",
    // `second` would be the following number,
    // `third` would be "all" or "mine"
});
```

Comment: shouldn't that be mystring.split(/,|_/);

Comment: Thanks for the link to the post - haven't seen that before. Good to know.

Comment: or even mystring.split(/[,_]/);

Comment: @Ken: yes, I meant to put `[,_]` - thanks for pointing that out, I'm a bit off my game today ;)

Comment: @Andy - gotta get your head back, dude

Answer (score 2):

Same, but loop

```
var myCommaStrings = myString.split(','); 
var myUnderscoreStrings = []; 
for (var i=0;i<myCommaStrings.length;i++) 
  myUnderscoreStrings[myUnderscoreStrings.length] = myCommaStrings[i].split('_');
```

Answer (score 1):

Throwing a wild guess, given your spec isn't complete:

```
var mystring = "mystring_109_all,mystring_110_mine,mystring_125_all";
var myarray = mystring.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
  myarray[i] = myarray[i].split("_");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split on commas and then on underscores, you'd have to iterate over the list:

```
var split1 = theString.split(',');
var split2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < split1.length; ++i)
  split2.push(split1[i].split('_'));
```

If you want to split on commas *or* underscores, you can split with a regex, but that's sometimes buggy. Here's a page to read up on the issues: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split

Answer (score 0):

Umm, the same way you would your original example:

```
var mystring = "mystring_109_all,mystring_110_mine,mystring_125_all";
var myarray = mystring.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a JavaScript functions-only library called [FuncJS](http://docs.funcjs.webege.com) which has a function called `split()` which would (hopefully) get the task done.

Read the docs and do download FuncJS, it's a very lightweight file.

Comment: could you please give a code example on how exactly your library would simplify the task. Just saying it's somewhere in the docs is not that helpful. Especially if you consider that more people than just the author might see your answer. Than everybody has to take the additional steps to see why exactly your solution might be superior.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Question is var str = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"; </p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Split Button</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<script>
var text = "";
function myFunction() {
    var str = "a,b,c,d,e,f";
    var arr = str.split(",");

    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; ++i){ 
        text += arr[i] +" ";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = arr[0];
}


</script>

</body>
</html>


**Answer**
a b c d e f g

Arr[0]=a
```

Comment: Answer
a b c d e f g

Comment: Answer Arr[0]=a