# How can I split in this code and store it in variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wanna split in this code and store it in three different variables, like `a=GD11`, `b=GDP7` and `c=GD11`, but I have problem that break in "s" shows result of "GDP7xGD11".

How can I break in separated three variables please help and suggest me.

```
var someString = "GD11sGDP7xGD11";
var lastWord = someString.split("s").pop();
alert(lastWord);
```

Comment: You can use regex `someString.split(/[sx]/g)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548307/javascript-split)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression `/[sx]/`

It will produce an array as follows.

```js
var someString = "GD11sGDP7xGD11";
        var lastWord = someString.split(/[sx]/);
      console.log(lastWord);
```

To sotre it in variable,

```js
var someString = "GD11sGDP7xGD11";
var lastWord = someString.split(/[sx]/);
a=lastWord[0];
b=lastWord[1];
c=lastWord[2];
console.log(a,b,c);
```